# How to make no one able to connect to my localserver except me?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, localhost, lamp

I've installed a LAMP server locally and I want it to only be accessible from my own computer (not even my local network), only through loopback. Is this possible to do securely? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Listen` directive in your config should be equal to `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: I looked at my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf (assuming this is the config file you mean) and I don't see any previous Listen commands. Am I in the wrong file? Pardon me for the noobness, first server setup.

Comment: the apache config can be split into several files, depending on what distribution you are using. go to `/etc/apache2` and do a `grep Listen * -r`. That will list the files with the `Listen` directive

Comment: Conveniently located in Listen.conf! I've changed it and restarted the service. Is there a way to test this from my local machine? Without having to pick up another computer and trying?

Comment: you can do a `netstat -nat | grep 80` and check whether port 80 is open on `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` or `your ip address:80`. For your case, it should be open only on `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

Tell the server to only listen on 127.0.0.1 and ::1.